# What is the best way to insert a record in log/history table in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

```
I have two models:
class RateCard(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    pricing_type = models.ForeignKey(PriceAttribute)

and 

class RateCardHistory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    pricing_type = models.ForeignKey(PriceAttribute)
```

what i want is on every operation in RateCard a new record should get insert RateCardHistory

Which one will best way to achieve this Django signals post_save or over ride the RateCard save method or is there any other approach which will be good.

Comment: Using the save method is more explicit and easier to understand. If you don't have a good reason for using signals, it's better to keep it simple.

Comment: Thanks @HåkenLid if you share any link/reference that will be very useful to me

Comment: How can i initiate or call RateCardHistory Model in RateCard save method to pass the RateCard values in RateCardHistory

Comment: do you want to add foreign key when you save it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ovveride the save method in `RateCard`

```
class RateCard(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    pricing_type = models.ForeignKey(PriceAttribute)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # the call to the super save the record as usual
        super(RateCard,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
        # do here what you want... create your new related records
        new_card_history = RateCardHistory.objects.create(name='the name', pricing_type=self)
```

I suggest you to do some changes to your code to. Add a creation datetime if you want to get the fields in order by creation and add also a related name to get the histories from `RateCard`

```
class RateCardHistory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    pricing_type = models.ForeignKey(PriceAttribute, related_name='histories')
```

Comment: Thanks @karim, I did that I initiate the RateCardHistory and passing field values as dictionary new_card_history=RateCardHistory(**data_dict), but the thing is it not getting saved .. I tried new_card_history.save()